# How do I ensure that HTML friendly parameters are passed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `Questions` with `Tags`.

When you click a tag name, it takes you to `/tagname`.

E.g. clicking `ruby` takes you to `/ruby`.

But, there are some tag names that need to be HTML escaped (e.g. `c#` or `.net`, etc.).

How do I do that?

I tried doing `params[:tag].html_safe` in my controller, but that doesn't do it because the params are being sent incorrectly before.

E.g. this is what the log looks like when I do click on the `c#` tag (or I manually type in `c#` in the URL).

```
Started GET "/c" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-29 07:31:46 -0500
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"tag"=>"c"}
  Tag Load (26.7ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."name" = 'c' LIMIT 1
```

This is what my route looks like:

```
get ':tag', to: 'home#index', as: :tag
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a 'slug' column to your Tag model, and store a name in a normalized form in it:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base 
  before_create :build_slug

  def build_slug
    self.slug = name.parameterize
  end
end
```

Add unique index on 'slug' column and find tags with Tag#find_by_slug

Or take a look at 'friendly_id' gem:
https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: That doesn't solve my issue. The tag slugs are still not the same as the name, in those cases (i.e. `c#`, `c++`, `.net`, etc.)

Comment: You can see more details at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707692/friendlyid-doesnt-build-html-escaped-slugs

Comment: Well, there is no point in having slug same as name, the point is to have slug in form that is allowed in URL